# How to copy a file from a location to another when a Docker container launches?

Tags: php, docker, copy, containers

Starting from a base image [php5.6](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/bfe27759103fa6050601060165409b5b3be06395/5.6/jessie/apache/Dockerfile) I am using the follow Dockerfile in order to create an image:

```
FROM php:5-apache

# Update apt-get
RUN apt-get update

## UTILITIES
RUN apt-get install -y vim
#RUN apt-get install -y wget


## APACHE2  basic installation
RUN apachectl -M
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod expires
RUN service apache2 restart
RUN apachectl -M


################################################
## PHP modules

RUN php -m

RUN apt-get install -y php5-common

RUN apt-get install -y php-calendar

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath

RUN apt-get install -y php5-mhash

RUN apt-get install -y php5-intl
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/intl.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/intl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/intl.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-mcrypt
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mcrypt.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-redis
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/redis.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/redis.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/redis.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-mysql
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mysql.so

RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d

RUN apt-get install -y php5-gd
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/gd.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gd.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-gdcm
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/gdcm.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gdcm.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gdcm.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-vtkgdcm
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/vtkgdcm.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/vtkgdcm.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/vtkgdcm.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-ldap
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/ldap.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/ldap.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/ldap.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-xsl
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/xsl.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xsl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xsl.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-tidy
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/tidy.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/tidy.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/tidy.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-xmlrpc
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/xmlrpc.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xmlrpc.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xmlrpc.so

RUN apt-get install -y php5-pgsql
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pgsql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pgsql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pgsql.so


RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mysqli.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysqli.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mysqli.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_mysql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_pgsql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_pgsql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_pgsql.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/readline.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/readline.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/readline.so

#RUN apt-get install -y php5-snmp
#RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/snmp.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/snmp.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/snmp.so


RUN php -m


## REDIS
RUN apt-get install -y telnet redis-server
RUN apt-get install -y redis-server
RUN apt-get install -y npm



# CONNECTIONS - PORTS
EXPOSE 80
```

When the container is running I see that php.ini was installed into `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` while the system expects it to be in `/usr/local/etc/php`, as sit in line 31 of the base image.

How can I copy the php.ini from `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` to `/usr/local/etc/php` before the container launches?

Comment: You might not want the same configuration the CLI uses for the web side. What you should do is copy a php.ini from your build environment into your image.

Comment: HI Jay, in fact this is only a test environment we don't have any previous php.ini. For that reason I was think in copy the php.ini from cli to  /usr/local/etc/php. If we will need any changes in any variables I can do that later. For that I decided to get access to the container through bash and copy using cp command and commit the image. What is werid is the fact the I can't see the php process and I dont know from where is comming the configuration for that php. Can you explain me?

Comment: PHP has a "default" configuration which is used if no php.ini is available.

Comment: I din't know that. Problem is solved.